# Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PatronWebUserUtility.PatronWebUserMaintenance'

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

We are attempting to publish a simple one-page ASPX/VB.NET application that manages a single table in a database and have hit a brick wall. When we run the application in Visual Studio, it runs perfectly. However after publishing to our IIS server (separate from our PC with Visual Studio) the application gets this error. We have tried LOTS of suggestions from other posts and nothing seems to make any difference in our instance.

The application is configured to build for .NET 4, and the IIS application pool is set to .NET 4 as well. the IIS server version is 8.0 running on Windows Server 2012 v6.2.

When publishing the application to the server, it generates this file structure:

bin (folder)

-PatronWebUserUtility.dll

-PatronWebUserUtility.pdb

-PatronWebUserUtility.xml

PatronWebUserMaintenance.ASPX

Web.Config

I included the above because I am not confident everything is publishing as it should, but I dont know how to verify what is actually publishing in the DLL. I assume the ASPX.VB page would be included there, but I just don't know.

We are not experienced in ASP at all, and are just trying to limp our way through this small project in the absence of an ASP developer in house. The code chunks below stop just before our actual application code, which I didn't think would be necessary for this query, but if you need more info to help, please ask!

## Error message:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PatronWebUserUtility.PatronWebUserMaintenance'.

Source Error: 



Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PatronWebUserMaintenance.aspx.vb" Inherits="PatronWebUserUtility.PatronWebUserMaintenance" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"%>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html>
  

 Source File:  /patronwebusermaintenance/PatronWebUserMaintenance.aspx    Line:  1 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36480
```

## ASPX Page Header:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="PatronWebUserMaintenance.aspx.vb" Inherits="PatronWebUserUtility.PatronWebUserMaintenance" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Patron Web User Maintenance</title>
</head>
```

## ASPX.VB Page Header:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Web.UI

Public Class PatronWebUserMaintenance
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

## Web Config:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PatronWebTestConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=PatronWebTest;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="PatronWebUserMaintenance.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
  
  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the folder directory about your IIS web site now? It seems that the IIS couldn't find the bin folder.

Comment: The folder is named PatronWebUserMaintenance in the inetpub folder on the server.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may set the IIS web site's the physical file path to the parent path not the right path.

I suggest you could try to modify the  physical file path  and try again.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IIS management console:

2.Find the web site you have used.

3.Right click the web site and select manage website and advanced settings

[image]

4.Modify the  physical path to patronwebusermaintenance instead of the inetpub folder.

[image]

Comment: The physical path is already set to "c:\inetpub\PatronWebUserMaintenance" Are you suggesting to move the directory out of inetpub, so the path is just c:\PatronWebUserMaintenance?

Comment: Could you please tell me which project you have created in the vs? ASP.NET Web site or ASP.NET web form application"?

Comment: ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) Visual Basic